# Python socket.recv evaluation

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a small python script in order to use it for checking haproxy. What the script does is to connect on haproxy socket and "poll" for stats.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys

my_socket = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM )

try:
  my_socket.connect( "/var/run/haproxy/haproxy.sock" )
except socket.error:
  print "cant connect to socket"
  sys.exit(1)

my_socket.send("show stat\n")
response = my_socket.recv(1024)
print response
```

What i wish to do is if there is no response from the socket, meaning if haproxy will not output the stats, to exit the script with exit code (1).Is it possible to somehow evaluate if an answer is received?

Comment: You mean if you don't get a response at the moment or do you want it to not block at all?

Comment: You can set a `timeout`. It's the max time to wait for a response

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed I mean if i don't get response. Assuming the script successfully send the command "show stat" but the other end does not repond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the socket will be in blocking mode and `recv()` will block until data is received or the connection is closed.

If you can assume that the proxy will respond within a certain amount of time you can set a timeout on the client socket. The timeout is the number of seconds to wait for a socket operation to complete. If the operation is not complete an exception is raised:

```
my_socket.settimeout(5.0)    # 5 seconds. Set this after connecting.
try:
    response = my_socket.recv(1024)
    print response
except socket.timeout as exc:
    print 'timed out waiting for response from proxy'
    my_socket.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```

That's one way and it's probably the easiest way. You could also look at the [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select) module which provides functions that will let your client wait for the socket to become readable, which indicates that there is data to be read, or that the socket has been closed. It really depends on what behaviour you want. Example using `select()`:

```
import select

r, _, _ = select.select([my_socket], [], [], 5.0)
if r:
    response = my_socket.recv(1024)
    print response
else:
    print 'Nothing received from proxy in 5 seconds'
    my_socket.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```